# Running dart in Android Studio 4.1.2: main.dart is automatically opened and made the selected file when running Flutter app

Tags: flutter, android-studio

After upgrading to Android Studio 4.1.2, every time I run my Flutter app, main.dart is automatically opened and made the selected file. How can I make this behaviour stop? When I run the app, I want the file that I'm currently editing to remain the selected file, as was the case prior to 4.1.2.

Comment: Also getting this on Flutter web, channel beta. My solution for now is to split the `main.dart` file horizontally and keep it open just a little

Comment: @Evan Good idea, that'll do for now - hopefully they'll sort this out soon. Thanks.